# t-sql merging two tables and replace null values

Tags: sql, t-sql, merge

I have these two tables, and that what I want is to compare them to know if there is any null value in table 2, if there is, replace the existing value in table 1 by the null value in table 2 (by the code column that is the primary key).

```
         Table 1
Code       Name          Points
 1     Juan Perez          10
 2     Marco Salgado       5
 3     Carlos Soto         9
 4     Alberto Ruiz        12
 5     Alejandro Castro    5
 10    Jonatan Polanco     0
 11    JD                 NULL


          Table 2
Code       Name          Points
 1     Juan Perez          10
 2     Marco Salgado       5
 3     Carlos Soto         9
 4     Alberto Ruiz        12
 5     Alejandro Castro    5
 10    Null                0
 11    JD                  9
```

The resulting table should look like this

```
         Table 2
Code       Name          Points
 1     Juan Perez          10
 2     Marco Salgado       5
 3     Carlos Soto         9
 4     Alberto Ruiz        12
 5     Alejandro Castro    5
 10    Jonatan Polanco     0
 11    JD                  9
```

Comment: I've tried merge and select clauses but nothing. I apreciate it your help

Comment: Doesn't "replace the existing value in table 1 by the null value in table 2" mean that your expected results should contain `'10'`/`NULL`/`'0'`, not `'10'`/`'Jonatan Polanco'`/`'0'`? And shouldn't the `'11'`/`'JD'`/`NULL` row remain unchanged? Please show us what you've tried and explain what didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to update the rows that have null values in Points column, You just need to join the two tables and add a where clause to limit the rows to the ones you want to update. Something like this

```
UPDATE t2
  SET Points = t.Points
FROM table_1 t
JOIN table_2 t2
  ON t.code = t2.code 
WHERE t2.Points IS NULL
```